# How would an economic collapse affect the people?

Tags: internal-consistency, apocalypse, post-apocalypse

If an economic collapse occurs, how it would affect the people. For example, would they go Mad Max or survive in it? Because I'm not certain.

Comment: This is a poor question for Worldbuilding. I did edit it to change "effect" to "affect", because with "effect", the question meant "how would an economic collapse cause people?" Which it might if people had more sex during an economic collapse, but I don't think that was your question! But even after my edit, this is WAAAAAY too broad to ever answer. Just think of all the effects (yes, "e" is correct in this case) of the 2008 collapse and how many news stories you read. The impact is endless. You're going to have to narrow this down.

Comment: This is too broad (You could write a thesis for an answer!), questions should be as focused as possible.  For example: what would be currency in the post-apocalypse?  The question also shows lack of research effort.

Comment: Why not go read up about Zimbabwe? They had an economic collapse and with sanctions they get very little support.

Answer (score 1):

Mankind is currently able to feed eight billion people (or more) because of a high **division of labor**. A farmer may grow grain, but he sells it and buys bread. If he had to mill grain and bake bread, he would not nearly be as effective at growing grain. And he wouldn't be able to grow nearly as much grain without farm machinery, and fertilizer, and so on. Another farmer raises pigs, and he might buy feed.

Most workers do highly specialized jobs. They don't produce food, they produce parts to produce parts to put food on the table. All this depends on **trust** and functioning **networks**. I go to the office to work where I earn **money** in a field that is unrelated to food, or housing, or most other survival needs. I have faith that people will find my work valuable enough to give me money to buy food, shelter, and other things.

A total economic collapse would lead to mass famine, and breakdown of society in the days running up to it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what counts as an economic collapse. Honestly I cannot think of a truly devastating worldwide economic collapse without World War 3 -- worldwide economic collapse and worldwide war are two faces of the same coin.

Excluding a devastating worldwide war, what would count as a real economic collapse? Obviously, an event which would disrupt and seriously depress the global markets in raw materials, services and manufactured goods. The most catastrophic scenario not induced by a world war that I can think of would be some sort of cold war opposing *both* India and China against North America and Europe. This is of course extremely unlikely, because at present the relations between India and China are such that if any one of them became locked in a cold war with the West the other would automatically side with the West; it is also very unlikely because whatever faults the Chinese Communist Party has it is not led by *stupid* men.

Supposing that such an unlikely scenario would happen, the effects would be severe for India and China but merely uncomfortable for the West. Taiwan would be toast, obviously, and Japan may have to align itself more closely with America. It may even have some positive effect on South America, which may have a shot at replacing India and China in their roles as manufacturers and suppliers of services.

Overall, a Mad Max-style situation is very unlikely without a worldwide war; I sincerely hope that world leaders will steer clear of a worldwide war.

Comment: Put on hold 40 mins ago and you managed to answer 1 minute ago. HOW?!

Comment: @Mołot: I began writing the answer more than one hour ago. It was hard to formulate an answer other that nope, Mad Max ain't gonna happen in the absence of world war three. I agree that it should be put on hold.